# How to save a binary image(with dtype=bool) using cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv in python and want to save a binary image(dtype=bool). If I simply use cv2.imwrite I get following error:

```
TypeError: image data type = 0 is not supported
```

Can someone help me with this? The image is basically supposed to work as mask later.

Answer (score 26):

You can use this:

```
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', maskimg * 255)
```

So this converts it implicitly to integer, which gives 0 for `False` and 1 for `True`, and multiplies it by 255 to make a (bit-)mask before writing it. OpenCV is quite tolerant and writes `int64` images with 8 bit depth (but e. g. `uint16` images with 16 bit depth). The operation is *not* done inplace, so you can still use `maskimg` for indexing etc.

Comment: Seems to work also simply as: `

cv2.imwrite("mask.png", 255 * binary_image)
`

Answer (score 2):

No `OpenCV` does not expects the binary image in the format of a boolean ndarray. `OpenCV` supports only `np.uint8`, `np.float32`, `np.float64`, Since OpenCV is more of an Image manipulation library, so an image with boolean values makes no sense, when you think of `RGB` or Gray-scale formats.

The most compact data type to store a binary matrix is `uchar` or `dtype=np.uint8`, So you need to use this data type instead of `np.bool`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the binary image to the 'uint8' data type.

Try this:

```
>>> binary_image.dtype='uint8'
>>> cv2.imwrite('image.png', binary_image)
```

Comment: need to use binary_image*255

Comment: @pippo1980 here as well I reverted your edit because it introduces code that breaks the answer. please don't do that.

Comment: But I tried and the resulting saved file is all black unless I add *255

Comment: (0) your edit introduced a typo. the code was invalid. (1) sure, you'd want to see something, but perhaps others want literally 0 and 1 (of range 255) in their image file. OpenCV does not appear able to save "1-bit" images. this answer did not discuss the outcome, so its intent was unclear. (2) other answers already presented what you think this one should be (`*255`). just upvote those. there is no point in "fixing" answers to all be essentially the same. if you think an answer is wrong enough to deserve it, you can downvote it

Comment: OpenCV does not appear able to save "1-bit" , OK thats what was the problem, I learnt a new thing today, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
ndarray.astype('bool')
```

See this page may help:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html

Comment: OP asked for a solution using CV2

Comment: the issue isn't usage of numpy (which is the data type instead of `cv::Mat` for the python bindings of OpenCV). the issue is that the array is *bool already*, so this does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using OpenCV, you should consider using hsv format for threshing the image. Convert the BGR image to HSV using `cv2.cvtColor()` and then threshold your image using `cv2.inRange()` function.

You would need values for the upper and lower limits for Hue(h), Saturation(s) and Value(v). For this you may use [this script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PNkZk-88u5vIUq6U9kLRtCDt_Nwqo5vx) or create your own using it as reference.

This script is meant to return hsv lower and upper limit values for live video stream input but with minor adjustments, you can do the same with image inputs as well.

Save the obtained binary(kind of) image using `cv2.imwrite()`, and there you have it. You may use this binary image for masking too. If you are still left with any doubts, you may refer to [this script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PgSrAG6m6K6JDL3nQbewpRNzKtXNcDB6) and it should clear most of them.